# Question about keep running a Javascript app on Synology NAS

Tags: javascript, linux, docker, synology, nas

my goal is to keep an app running on my Synology, i can run the app connecting in SSH and everything is fine but when i close the connection obviously the app stop to work.

I'm not very expert with Unix and co. so my actual workaround for this is that:

Guacamole Docker + Firefox Docker: I connect to the firefox docker, then use guacamole for the ssh and run the app from there. I can close everything and the app is still running fine. But I know I'm wasting so much everything for an easy task.

I know for sure that there is a better way to accomplish that so can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you start something in a shell, that something is bound to that shell, so when you terminate the shell (like when you close the ssh connection) whatever was bound to it also terminates.

For your process to survive the shell termination, you have to detach it, there are various ways to do it and I'm not experienced in the specific unix distribution that Synology uses so I can't be 100% sure but this will probably work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

It uses a software, tmux, to do the detatching thing.

That said, using docker is not a bad idea. I don't think there will be any noticeable performance difference or wasted resources.